# Can cleveref treat sections in other chapters as chapters?

Tags: cleveref

I am using cleveref for my thesis. When referencing another chapter, if I put the label at the top of the chapter, it will say "chapter X", but if I put the label after defining a new section or subsection, it will say "section X.Y", etc.

For consistency it would be nice to have everything referred to as "chapter" in this case. Is it possible to get cleveref to refer to sections in other chapters as chapters?

(NB: The thing I'd really like to do which may be difficult would be to have this only work for *other* chapters, so if I reference section Y within the current chapter, it would still say "section." But I recognize this may be quite challenging!)

Comment: Please provide a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that shows what you're doing at the moment. Be sure to indicate which document class you use.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy, I use this for documents in Norwegian (agreements and memos):

```
%% Referanser   
\RequirePackage{cleveref}
\IfLanguageName{norsk}{%
        \Crefname{section}{Punkt}{Punktene}
        \Crefname{subsection}{Punkt}{Punktene}
        \crefname{section}{punkt}{punktene}
        \crefname{subsection}{punkt}{punktene}
    }{}
```

To have everything referred to as chapters, use:

```
%% References   
\RequirePackage{cleveref}
\IfLanguageName{English}{%
        \Crefname{section}{Chapter}{Chapters}
        \Crefname{subsection}{Chapter}{Chapters}
        \crefname{section}{chapter}{chapters}
        \crefname{subsection}{chapter}{chapters}
    }{}
```

To achieve you second goal, I would personally chosen a manual approach and use the classic reference system, i.e. when in the same chaper, I would have used:

```
... see subsection~\ref{sec:section-label-in-the-current-chapter}
```

Not very fancy, but easy and much better than a complicated macro. Sometimes the simple solution is the best.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it's possible to have it distinguish between references within and outside the current chapter? It would be nice for sections within the current chapter to still be called "section."

Comment: @Adam, then you might have to specify a method to determine which chapter we are currently in. I can thing of a few ways. However, as a reader I might find it odd so see a reference to Chapter 4.5. In my book that *is* Section 4.5.

Comment: @daleif thanks, I'm still wrestling with it myself. For me it's a bit strange to have the choice to refer to Chapter 4 or Section 4.5 if I want to be specific about where in Ch. 4 the thing I'm mentioning is located.

Comment: I think for most people the form of the number is selv explanatory. However you sometimes see some 'strange' people who numbers sections as 1,2,3 in each chapter. In which case you do need some kind of remedy when refering inside or outside the chapter. A construction like this is *not* something I would recommend as it might be more confusing than helpful to the casual reader.

Comment: @Adam Yes, it is of course possible, but it will depend on how (and if) you are numbering you chapters, sections, etc. Put the current chapter number in one variable, put the other chapters number in another, and compare. You may have to split the section number. I do not have the skills do write such macro. I have indicted a simple solution in the answer.

Comment: @daleif If your second comment was addressed to me: In Norwegian (as in Danish) in a short and structured text as for example an agreement, it is sometimes correct to refer to both chapter, sections, subsections etc. as ‘punkt’ as in ‘*se punkt 2.4.3 foran*’.

Comment: @daleif - I used to work for an institution whose in-house guide for working papers prohibited [!] the use compound numbers subsections and subsubsections. Instead, sections had to be numbered uppercase-Roman, subsection numbers were in uppercase-Alpha, and subsubsection numbers in arabic.  Cross-referencing material in other sections tended to be tricky, to say the least. I ended up writing a LaTeX package (for those of us who used LaTeX -- we were quite a nice-sized group) which automatically prefixed higher-level sectioning numbers to lower-level sectioning numbers. Somehow that was OK...

Comment: @Sveinung, it was for Adam. However I do not quite understand your point. If I'm referring to subsection 4 og section 2 in chapter 6, I of course write section 6.2.4. In most cases it does not make sense to refer to it as subsection, this is evident from the number. We do the same thing in danish where everything under chapter are *afsnit*.  The exact danish word for paragraph is rarely used in everyday texts.

Comment: @Mico, but why? Luckily we tend to have free range, and thus follow books that we like plus a lot of common sense.

Comment: @daleif Maybe I was unclear, but we refer to the same practise, referring to a subsection as a compound numbered section (afsnit 2.3.3/avsnitt 2.3.3/punkt 2.3.3). But strictly speaking, the correct reference is to subsection (underafsnit 2.3.3/underavsnitt 2.3.3/underpunkt 2.3.3). So if you refer to chapter 2.3.4 or section 2.3.4 is mostly a matter of taste. My preference (and recommendation) is to refer to chapter and section, but leave the subsections *etc*.